# Liferay: how to prevent landing pages (login and logout) from being shown in the menu?

Tags: liferay

I'm trying to find a clean way so that the login and logout pages for my liferay portal aren't shown in my menu. For the login page I guess I could move the user to the private pages section but I have no clue how I can make the logout landing page not visible. And preferably the logout page would only be navigable to when you're effectively logged out so users can't accidentally go to it when they've got the url cached in their browser.

Any input would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding hiding the landing pages: Just create them and check "hidden" in "Manage Page" for that page. This will make the page accessible according to the permissions, but hide it in the navigation - e.g. if you know the page's name, you can go there - just as you requested.

If you display the currently logged in user on the logout landing page (e.g. through the "Sign In" portlet, you don't need to display a message like "you've been logged out", but display the current state of the user's session.

Of course you're free to not use the Sign-In opportunity on that page, in this case you'll have to display the current session state in a different portlet. It could be as simple as a templated WebContent portlet, accessing the currently logged in user.

**Edit**: If you set default.logout.page.path=/web/guest/logout and auth.forward.by.last.path=true but you're still not redirected on logout, chances are that changes made through the UI override your portal-ext.properties. If you've edited "Settings" in ControlPanel, this is most likely the case. You can set these values there, on the first page in settings.

As noted in your comment: You cannot make the first page hidden. This shouldn't be a problem: Just make any other page hidden. Even if you don't have more public content than this, you can have at least a public page stating that you need to login. Make this the first, so the logout page can be either a child page of this or a new toplevel page - but most importantly: It can be hidden.

Comment: Sorry for the late response, when I try to do this it says that the first page can not be hidden.

Comment: well - then make any other but the first page your default logout page. Just mark it hidden. Editing the answer for more clarification - I've tried this and it works.

Comment: Indeed, it seems to work for the logout page, but the login page is another issue.

Comment: login page? works for me... try entering the URL in the control-panel, section "settings"

Comment: It says at least one page needs to be visible. And since the others aren't visible to non logged in users...

Comment: create one page - visible - that says "please log in". In whatever graphical design you want. This is the one visible page you have. Then create a login and a logout page, make both hidden (or, for the login page, private). Voila.